# signal to stop VS. signal sb to stop

Tags: collocations, to-infinitive

Is the following use of **signal to stop** natural?

> John pulled over to the side of the road when he saw a policeman **signaling to stop**.

If it's natural, what does it mean and how does it differ from "signaling him to stop"?

A related question is whether to insert the preposition *to* or *for* between *signaling* and *him*.

Answer (score 2):

The policeman was signaling.  In this case, the signal was "to stop".  It was not directed at any particular motorist, but just a general signal to everyone, including John.

Examples:

> The foreman **signaled to shut down the production line**.
>
> The publicist **signaled that the interview was over**.

In both of these cases the signal was directed to everyone, with the assumption that the relevant people would see it and take appropriate action.

As you note, you can also signal *to* someone, if you want to communicate specifically with them:

> The policeman **signaled to John** to pull over.
>
> The sergeant **signaled to the soldiers** to fall out of formation.

The preposition is (normally) optional, but if you use one it should be "to" the intended recipient.  "For" is used to describe the signal itself.

> The event coordinator signaled **to** the band leader to start the music.
>
> The event coordinator signaled **for** the music to start.

You can also say something like:

> The event coordinator signaled **for** the band leader to start the music.

but note that this tells us about the *purpose* of the signal.

Comment: The event coordinator signaled the band leader to start the music. Is it correct? Why/Why not?

Comment: Yes, the preposition is optional. "The policeman signaled John to pull over" is grammatical.   I couldn't tell you why, though -- I read somewhere that certain English grammar has become more simplified over time.

Comment: Who knows if this would considered off-the-wall, but **signal** + infinitive is like a catenative verb; with **him** as direct object, it's like a ditransitive verb with dativisation.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, what does 'dativisation' mean? I just can't find this word in any dictionaries.